# java.util.Properties ignoring ${...} placeholders

Tags: java

Anyone happen to come come across a use case where one has to stick to `java.util.Properties.load` method to read all the key-value pairs from a `.properties` file but at the same time to be environment/profile specific, placeholders, `${...}` are used?

I'm building a spring boot app. and have profile specific properties files and placeholders work fine in them. However, the app. is dependent on a relatively older app that reads a property file from `java.util.Properties.load` method and in doing so the placeholders are being ignored. Since this is an old app. and do not want to change at this point in time, anyone has any suggestions on how do I go about?

Comment: The `Properties` class has no concept of placeholders.

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/StrSubstitutor.html  can be useful to help you do the substitution.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Maven, you can write a generic properties file as such:

```
prop.1=${val1}
prop.2=${val2}
...
```

Then using the [Filtering feature](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) of the Maven Resources Plugin, you can do the replace your placeholders depdending on your maven profile.